# Just want to upload a file using Postman - error Content-Type must be application/json

Tags: postman

I just want to upload a file to couchdb using Postman

1. I add new POST request
2. Body form-data, add key and choose file and select file
3. I set nothing else and hit RUN

Note: I've searched and searched and watched videos where this works fine, but for the life of me I cannot get it to work.

[Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Luu1N.png)

[Postman console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBs7z.png)

I also tried adding file using binary - that did not work either.